# Calculate math equation from string (+, -, /, *)

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to make a tiny math library for super basic calculations such as: addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

But I'm having issues with my 'Parse' method which is supposed to work as a method for calculating a equation contained within a string by splitting all variables withing the string into seperate variables such as "5*5+2" becomes:

```
5, 
*, 
5, 
+, 
2
```

My current code:

```
    private static double Parse(string ParseEquation)
    {
        string[] split = Regex.Split(ParseEquation, @"(?<=[+-/*])");

        List<string> keywords = new List<string>();

        foreach (string i in split)
        {
            var var1 = Regex.Match(i, @"\d+").Value;
            keywords.Add(var1);

            var var2 = Regex.Match(i, @"([+-/*])").Value;
            keywords.Add(var2);
        }

        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            string keyword = keywords[i + 1];

            if (keyword == "+")
                sum = Addition(sum, double.Parse(keywords[i]));
            if (keyword == "-")
                sum = Subtraction(sum, double.Parse(keywords[i]));
            if (keyword == "/")
                sum = Division(sum, double.Parse(keywords[i]));
            if (keyword == "*")
                sum = Multiplication(sum, double.Parse(keywords[i]));
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

The methods: Addition(), Subtraction(), Divion() and Multiplication() works as expected (tested through unit tests).

So I need help with what to change in my Parse method as the output is always wrong no matter what I try.

(Complete code: [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/yezusalagi.cs))

Comment: This is your chance to learn real parsing. Check out ANTLR or similar parser/lexers.

Comment: ...or first write RPN parser

Comment: ...or use parser combinators. https://github.com/datalust/superpower has great examples

Comment: The canonical way to do this sort of thing is to write a "lexer" which takes the incoming string and splits it up into tokens. Each token has a value and a type. Write a method which returns a token stream: ( ("55", Number), ("*", Operator), ("5", Number), ("+", Operator), ("2", Number) ). Then your parser works on that. If you get into stuff like `(5 * 5 + (3 / 2 * pow(5,6) - 3))`, you're going to find yourself in deep waters: Infix expressions are relatively difficult to parse. Patrick and Selvin offer good advice. [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) is a good start.

Comment: I totally second the comment by Patrick Hoffman; the task you are trying to accomplish is not rocket science, but it is not trivial either. I have implemented a similar parser (also in C#) which took me several days - although the implemetation does not use much code. Your implementation has no mechanism to resolve function precedence (such as multiplication would be evaluated before addition) and for recognizing terms in parenthesis. However, I find the downvote not justified.

Comment: Ed is correct. **Start by writing a lexer**. Parsers are not difficult if you get the architecture correct, but you have no architecture at all.  A lexer turns text into a sequence of tokens. A parser turns a sequence of tokens into a syntax tree. An execution engine runs a syntax tree.  So you need at least a class for each of those concepts.

Comment: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ExpressionParser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed your problem by doing the following changes.

1. Initialize your `sum` with the first number:

   ```
   double sum = double.Parse(keywords[0]);
   ```
2. Change your for loop to a step of two and start the loop at 2

   ```
   for (int i = 2; i < keywords.Count - 1; i += 2)
   ```
3. Change the keyword to get the it by i - 1

   ```
   string keyword = keywords[i - 1];
   ```

Those changes will give the result `27`.

Here is the complete code:

```
private static double Parse(string ParseEquation)
{
    string[] split = Regex.Split(ParseEquation, @"(?<=[+-/*])");

    List<string> keywords = new List<string>();

    foreach (string i in split)
    {
        var var1 = Regex.Match(i, @"\d+").Value;
        keywords.Add(var1);

        var var2 = Regex.Match(i, @"([+-/*])").Value;
        keywords.Add(var2);
    }

    double sum = double.Parse(keywords[0]);

    for (int i = 2; i < keywords.Count - 1; i += 2)
    {
        string keyword = keywords[i - 1];

        if (keyword == "+")
            sum = Addition(sum, double.Parse(keywords[i]));
        else if (keyword == "-")
            sum = Subtraction(sum, double.Parse(keywords[i]));
        else if (keyword == "/")
            sum = Division(sum, double.Parse(keywords[i]));
        else if (keyword == "*")
            sum = Multiplication(sum, double.Parse(keywords[i]));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this sample](https://github.com/datalust/superpower/tree/dev/sample/IntCalc) is exactly the thing you're trying to build:

```
PS> IntCalc.exe 5*5+2
27
```

It's only 158 lines of code and really a good chance to learn about [parser combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinator).

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I'm not looking for a complete change of code as the current structure is what is required (assignment).